# Python Erro no if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, pandas

Estou a ter um erro no if e não sei como corrigir este erro, estou a usar o Python 3.6 e Pandas para leitura, escrita e data analysis.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("JonnyTheBoy10.csv", usecols=['ART_TIPO', 'ART_DESIG', 'PORTA', 'CP4', 'CP3', 'LOCALIDADE'])
df2 = pd.read_csv("JonnyTheBoyFull.csv", usecols=['ART_TIPO', 'ART_DESIG', 'PORTA', 'CP4', 'CP3', 'LOCALIDADE'])

    if df1["CP4"] == df2["CP4"] and df1["CP3"] == df2["CP3"]
```

Tenho este erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User01/Desktop/Normmm/Norm.py", line 11, in <module>
    if df1["CP4"] == df2["CP4"] and df1["CP3"] == df2["CP3"]:
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 818, in wrapper
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok, depois do verdadeiro chat nos comentários, e vc ter me mandado os csv's, "resolvi o seu problema" (que isso não se repita, ahahaha), vamos lá. O problema é que vc precisa comparar cada linha dos dataframes, e voce esta comparando as colunas inteiras, isso não pode; mesmo porque os dataframes tem tamanhos diferentes (por isso da o erro), fiz testes com os csv's que vc me enviou, nenhuma linha do csv menor é totalmente identica à linha relativa (mesmo indice) ao csv maior, veja o codigo:

[Clique aqui para ver codigo abaixo rodando.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/diff-df1/notebook)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("JonnyTheBoy10.csv", usecols=['ART_TIPO', 'ART_DESIG', 'PORTA', 'CP4', 'CP3', 'LOCALIDADE'])
df2 = pd.read_csv("JonnyTheBoyFull.csv", usecols=['ART_TIPO', 'ART_DESIG', 'PORTA', 'CP4', 'CP3', 'LOCALIDADE'])

all_equals=[]
cp3_equal=[]
cp4_equal=[]

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if str(row.CP4)==str(df2.CP4[index]) and str(row.CP3)==str(df2.CP3[index]):
        all_equals.append(row)

    if  str(row.CP3)==str(df2.CP3[index]):
        cp3_equal.append(row)

    if str(row.CP4)==str(df2.CP4[index]):
        cp4_equal.append(row)  


print ('Igualdades em ambos: ', len(all_equals))
print ('Igualdades em CP3: ', len(cp3_equal))
print ('Igualdades em CP4: ', len(cp4_equal))

Igualdades em ambos:  0
Igualdades em CP3:  9
Igualdades em CP4:  0
```

---

> Vou deixar a explicação inicial (abaixo) porque pode servir para outras pessoas em outros contextos.

**Veja esse exemplo:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['C', 'D'], ['A', 'B']])
df1==df2
       0      1
0  False  False
1  False  False
```

Agora, o mesmo exemplo, mas com o df2 'indexado'.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['C', 'D'], ['A', 'B']], index=[1,0])
df1==df2
....
raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
...
```

Veja que foi levantado uma exceção com o mesmo erro que vc relata, eu suprimi a msg inteira para ficar mais fácil.

> Solução 1: Drope os indices:

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True) == df2.reset_index(drop=True)
       0      1
0  False  False
1  False  False
```

> Solução 2: Faça sort em axis=0:

```
df1.sort_index()==df2.sort_index()
      0     1
0  True  True
1  True  True
```

Note que == é 'sensitivo' à ordem das colunas.

> Aplicando ao exemplo da sua questão.

No caso da sua questão, tente apenas mudar o `if` para:

```
if df1.reset_index(drop=True)["CP4"] == df2.reset_index(drop=True)["CP4"] and
df1.reset_index(drop=True)["CP3"] == df2.reset_index(drop=True)["CP3"]
```

Comment: Não entendi nada

Comment: Editei a resposta e mudei seu if, experimente e veja se funciona.

Comment: tive o mesmo erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User01/Desktop/Normmm/Norm.py", line 12, in <module>
    if df1.reset_index(drop=True)["CP4"] == df2.reset_index(drop=True)["CP4"] and df1.reset_index(drop=True)["CP3"] == df2.reset_index(drop=True)["CP3"]:
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 818, in wrapper
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Todo o codigo que tenho feito ate agora https://pastebin.com/DTcTUV6M

Comment: Agora vc precisa "tatear", tente primeiro converter todos os df dropando os indices, tipo df11 = df1.reset_index(drop=True), df22= df2.reset_index(drop=True) ... Depois compare os novs dfs um a um, de preferencia no console, talvez assim vc descubra o q esta causando o erro

Comment: Tenho o mesmo erro.

Comment: Se quiser me mandar os csv's eu testo p vc.

Comment: Pode ser, estou a usar o PyCharm e o anaconda

Comment: O que vc usa não importa, eu só preciso dos arquivos csv.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DTcTUV6M   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdEKGO_S6HDVUZoa05BZ2hEQkE/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdEKGO_S6HDeXQzSWxEbWdpOWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Vc mandou somente 1, como vou fazer a comparação? Para fazer o teste eu teria que ter os 2 arquivos csv.

Comment: estao dois links 1 -
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdEKGO_S6HDeXQzSWxEbWdpOWs/view e 2 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdEKGO_S6HDVUZoa05BZ2hEQkE/view

Comment: Ok, vou testar mais tarde.

Comment: Me explique uma coisa, qual é o seu objetivo com aquele `if`? voce poderia editar a msg e acrescentar o bloco do `if` completo?

Comment: esse if serve, se encontrar uma morada na df2 com o CP4 e o CP3 iguais vai escrever numa outra tabela e depois e feita uma analise sobre essas linhas que tem correspondência, com o fim de encontrar a morada correta

Comment: Então.... Seu `if` esta errado, coloque o bloco do if na msg para que fique ainda mais claro do q ve quer, que eu o corrijo.

Comment: if df1['CP4'] == df2['CP4'] and df1["CP3"] == df2["CP3"]:
            # compara as colunas CP4 e CP3 da df1(morradas incompletas e erradas) com a df2(moradas corretas)
            # Escreve num csv teporario com todas as matchs
            # se encontrar so uma match escreve no csv norm.csv
            # se não faz a semelhança, com maior match é normalizado

Comment: Vc não desenvolveu o codigo dentro do `if` ainda?

Comment: Ok, editei a resposta e coloquei a solução especifica para o seu problema, agora é só fazer as adptações ao seu contexto.